# What kind of encoding is this string?

Tags: php

To keep it simple to explain:
I moved a bunch of folders to my linux VPS
This is the original name:

> Rodinné záležitosti

And the folders name became like so:

> Rodinn#U00e9 z#U00e1le#U017eitosti

And when I enter via Browser on the folder this is the url

> www.localhost/folders/Rodinn%23U00e9%20z%23U00e1le%23U017eitosti/

How can I from this string: "Rodinné záležitosti" get the folder url?

Comment: Looks like `#U00e9` has to be replaced with the Unicode code point `0x00e9`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a different question in your title than your body.

For your title question, it is [unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

For your body answer, I am guessing that you have not set a character encoding. Try UTF-8 as it's a recommended standard, and hopefully the character encoding that whatever function or software you are using to read the folder name is assuming that you are using.

Please share the code that you are using to read folder names so then it's possible to let you know -how- to set your character encoding.

FYIL

```
Rodinn#U00e9 z#U00e1le#U017eitosti
```

with a bit of a clean up:

```
Rodinn\u00e9 z\u00e1le\u017eitosti
```

ran through a [unicode to text converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter):

```
Rodinné záležitosti
```

Comment: Thanks so far for the help, I didn't use any type of encoding to read the folder names, I had them on Windows and I saved the names to a database, then I moved them to linux and the names just went crazy

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. I am reading a array file of names and while i'm reading I add the name to a database and I create the folder with that name. Then I moved it to Linux and the names because like this: Rodinn#U00e9 z#U00e1le#U017eitosti

Comment: Well you will need to set the character encoding for your database. If you are using mysql, you can simple use `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Comment: I did that already, and the names are like so: Rodinné záležitosti but the problem is the folders name Rodinn#U00e9 z#U00e1le#U017eitosti. I need to convert Rodinné záležitosti to Rodinn#U00e9 z#U00e1le#U017eitosti using php

Comment: You don't want to convert the `#U00e1` string into `é` using PHP, you want to keep your character encoding consistent across the whole of your flow. Which means saving into your database with utf8 character encoding, and reading from your database with utf8 character encoding. Then, where the text will be displayed, make sure to set utf8 character coding here too. If you are displaying it on a webpage, and you use the `charset` attribute on the `meta` tag.

Comment: I don't want to convert the "#U00e1" string into "é". I want to convert the "é" into "#U00e1"

Comment: Oh okay, well I wasn't following. Well what you are seeing in the hexadecimal representation of your character. Since there is no native hexadecimal converter in PHP, you have to go through decimal. So character > decimal > hex, using `ord` and `dechex` respectively. So you will end up with: `dechex(ord('é'))` which will give you `e9`, and as you may have noticed, this is the value of your first character: `#U00e9`